# Why can't I use this variable?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use the object variable in the array to compare with the user input to see if they have an appointment this month. When ran I get an undefined method error for month after the a[i]. Is there anyway to call the attributes I have listed?

```
class Month < Appointment
  attr_accessor :des, :day, :month, :year

  class << self
    def occurOn2(a,uDay, uMonth, uYear)
      appts = 0

      for i in (0..10) do
        if  a[i].month == uMonth  
          puts "You're #{a[i].des} is scheduled for this month #{a[i].month} "
          appts =+ 1
        end
      end
      if appts < 1 
        puts "You do not have any appointments at this time."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". You need to show how the code is called. I'd also suggest using proper indentation. It'll make your code more readable and more easily maintained.

Comment: Yes my apologies, I have a long list of code so thought just posting the part I'm having a problem with would suffice but I did not give proper explanation. The uDay, uMonth , etc... are user inputed to see if there is something conflicting with the date.

Comment: I put all of the appointments in an array and wanted to cross check them with the user input except I am getting an error for an undefined method when trying to get the month from the object in the array.

Comment: Also thanks for cleaning up my code.

Comment: What does `10` signify here in `0..10`? Why is that a limit? What does it represent? In Ruby `for` is hardly ever used. Instead try: `11.times do |i|`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could use a refactor (10 seems like a 'magic number') but I think this error you speak of could be resolved with a simple nil check.

```
 for i in (0..10) do
    if a[1] # or "if defined?(a[1].month)" if you want to be more specific
      if  a[i].month == uMonth  
        puts "You're #{a[i].des} is scheduled for this month #{a[i].month} "
        appts =+ 1
      end
    end
 end
```

Comment: Also `for` is discouraged in Ruby. `10.times do |i|` would accomplish the same thing without leaking `i` and would be idiomatic.